# Knowing when rendering complete view/subview or just subview

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is a backbone thing that has got me thinking for a while.

Think of this setup: we are currently on `/location` and the location view is rendered. In which we want a block to be a subview that changes. Say we navigate to `/location/france`, in the router we can say to just render this subview with France and it will have no problems. But when you refresh or navigate directly though the addressbar to `/location/france` the parent view isnt loaded.

What is a nice way to make this difference. Knowing when to render the full page or just a small part.

Comment: when you refresh the page it loads all the templates and js again, So it also refreshes its history. I got same problem while developing one requirement. What i have done is I have kept my rout change in local storage and after refresh I fetched the last visited rout from local storage and rendered it again.

Comment: its not so much about the history, but if i need to render the parent view as well. `/location` renders the parent view, `/france` the subview. `/location/france` (direct entry) must render both.